# Forbidden Error after ssh transfer from plesk to cpanel

Tags: wordpress, ssh, cpanel, plesk, whm

I moved several WordPress install from a server that is running Plesk to one that is running WHM/cPanel. After the move I am unable to access the site. I get:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I also get:

> 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have checked all the permissions and owners but everything seems to be fine but still nothing is working. I am not sure what to do now.

My process for transferring the site was to `tar httpdocs` using ssh to connect to the Plesk server then I replaced the `public_html` directory with the contents of the `httpdocs.tar.gz` on the cPanel server.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group needed to be changed on the public_html file to "nobody". The group was still set as the set group in Plesk.

```
chown owner:group folder
```

Answer (score 0):

The files might have too much rights or too less or they are owned by the wrong user. Please check which user is supposed to own them and run the following comments:

```
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo chown webuser:webuser -R /var/www/
```

Replace *webuser* with the right user and */var/www/* with the right directory.